# Python Calling global dictionary in another method

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have created and populated a dict in my readfiles.py? and now I need to call this Dict for use in another method in a For loop to see if i can match words from another list called CategoryGA to words that are in the sentences Cleanse variable in populated dict:

my dict is populated with a chat between two people this is a segment of the output from the dict:

```
{0: ['hi'], 1: ['32 m fresno'], 2: ['u?'], 3: ['"33/f/ca', ' how r u?"'],  4: ['got a cam?']}
```

The key value for this dict is the linenum and the variable Cleanse is the chat.

readfiles.py

```
import re
import os

Chatfile = 'ChatLogs/#######/Chat1.txt'
Lexfile = 'Lexicons/########.txt'
cleanChat = dict()

def ReadChat():

    with open(Chatfile) as file_read:
        chat_content = file_read.readlines()
        for linenum, line in enumerate(chat_content):
            Regex = re.sub('<.*?>[^\S\r\n]', '', line)
            #cleanChat = Cleanse
            #print(linenum, cleanChat)
            Cleanse = Regex.rstrip("\n").split(",")

            cleanChat[linenum] = Cleanse

    file_read.close()

ReadChat()
```

main.py

```
from collections import Counter

from Categories.GainingAccess import GA
from Readfiles import *



CategoryGA = GA
Hits = []
cleansedLex = []



   def SpeechActCounter():
      for line in cleanChat.values():
        for section in line:
            if any(word in section for word in CategoryGA):
                print(section)
                #if any(word in line for word in CategoryGA):
                print(line)
                Word_Hit = False
                for word in CategoryGA:
                    if line.find(word) != -1:
                        Word_Hit = True
                        Hits.append(word)
                        print('%s appeared on Line %s' % (word))

    count = Counter(Hits)
    count.keys()
    for key, value in count.items():
        print(key, ':', value)
    SpeechActCounter()
```

This is my error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Lewis Collins/Desktop/Test/main.py", line 32, in <module>
    SpeechActCounter()
  File "C:/Users/Lewis Collins/Desktop/Test/main.py", line 22, in SpeechActCounter
    if line.find(word) != -1:
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'find'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Output:

```
['hi asl?']
```

I receive limited output and the for loop seems to be broken  as it does not attempted to match words in if statement and the print statement at bottom does not get reached.

Contents of my CategoryGA:

```
import re

GA = ["face", "cam", "donkey"]
```

Comment: GA is being pulled in from another page i will post its contents in question

Comment: You don't have lines. You have *integer keys*. `for line in cleanChat` produces the keys of the dictionary. So `word in line` tries to test against an integer here. `in` expects the right-hand operand to be iterable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are iterating over the dictionary *keys* here:

```
for line in cleanChat:
```

Your keys are integers (line *numbers*), not strings or lists, so the `word in line` test complains because the right-hand operand, `line` is not an iterable object (integers are not containers, they don't contain other objects, so testing for membership makes no sense).

If you wanted to loop over the *values*, do so explicitly:

```
for line in cleanChat.values():
```

That way `line` is set to one of the lists in the dictionary, each a result of the `Regex.rstrip("\n").split(",")` operation.

Comment: ah right i see what you mean so i would state my for loop as "for line in cleanChat.Cleanse():"

Comment: @L.C: no, as `for line in cleanChat.values()`.

Comment: ♦ right i see what you mean it's a good explanation thank you. I've corrected my code but now when I am running it I do not receive any output like my code isn't even acknowledging this print statement in main print('%s appeared on Line %s' % (word))

Comment: @L.C: well, are you trying to test if `word` is in the *list*, or in any of the strings contained *in* that list. Remember that `line` is set to lists like `['"33/f/ca', ' how r u?"']`; are you testing for `'how'` or are you testing for `' how r u?"'`? The latter would work, the former wouldn't.

Comment: I would be testing if any of the words contained in CategoryGA was in line then if it is print that line it appeared on, but i suppose if i'm correct in thinking here so line is now the whole list rather than individual segments. Which leaves me to ask how would i get it to work in the sense of for example if how was in my GA list, once it is found in segment 'how r u' how do i get it to print that.

Comment: @L.C: you'd have to use a loop `for section in line:`, then then test each section against the words. Note that your `if any(..)` test is redundant if you are going to loop over `CategoryGA` *again*. May as well skip the `if` and go straight to the loop.

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you mean here or an article/website of something i could read on this. I understand the for section in line but not why i would be leaving out my if statement. Thanks in advance for your help so far

Comment: I'm adding my most up to date code of what I've tried along with an error and output

Comment: Issue seems to be resolved after some tweaking and revision of your advice and i can now mark this question as answered Thanks for all your help and enjoy rest of your day